# How do you use logarithmic differentiation to differentiate $y=\frac{e^{-x}\cos^2x}{x^2+x+1}$

Tags: calculus

How do you use logarithmic differentiation to differentiate $y=\frac{e^{-x}\cos^2x}{x^2+x+1}$.

I can take the logarithm on both sides $\ln(y)=\ln(\frac{e^{-x}\cos^2x}{x^2+x+1})$

That would be $\ln(y)=\ln(e^{-x}\cos^{2}x)-\ln(x^2+x+1)$

$=\ln(y)=\ln(e^{-x})+\ln(2\cos(x))-\ln(x^2+x+1)$

$=\ln(y)=-x+\ln(2\cos(x))-\ln(x^2+x+1)$

What should I do next with this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate both sides with respect to x (using the chain rule on the LHS since $y$ is a function of $x$) to get that
$$
\frac{y'}{y}=-1-\frac{2\sin x}{2\cos x}+\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+1}.
$$
Now solve for $y'$ by multiplying both sides by $y$. (recall that $y=\frac{e^{-x}\cos^2x}{x^2+x+1}$).